# Closure Table Insert Query

Tags: mysql

I have a closure table design as follows:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| referral_id | referrent_id | level |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

Basically ancestor, descendant and depth. I'm trying to do an insert but my sql query does not seem to be working.

```
INSERT INTO referral_referent (referral_id, referent_id, level) VALUES
(SELECT referral_id, 3, level+1 FROM referral_referent
WHERE referent_id = 1
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, 0);
```

This is the error that was generated:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT referral_id, 3, level+1 FROM referral_referent WHERE
>   descendant = 1 UNI' at line 2

Comment: Drop `VALUES` from the statement.  Check the syntax for an "insert into ... select" statement.

Comment: ah ok, cause phpmyadmin sql editor was showing an error at union so I thought adding `values` would fixed it. Thanks